Were there any Vaishnavite Sri Vidya practitioners?
Are there any Sri Vidya upasakas who also had Vaishnavite inclinations? i.e They must have worshipped both Mahavishnu and Maha Tripura Sundari, and attained siddhi. Sparing Bilvamangala Thakur, who worshipped Gopala Sundari.

In the modern times, Sri M (It appears so based on his youtube lectures). He seems quite open to Vaishnavism and gives initaition in Kriya and Sri Vidvya sadhana. Govinda das Kaviraj was a Shakta & later turned to Gaudiya Vaishnavism.
